# Jquery ajax call result cache problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, caching

I am making an ajax call as follows setting cache: true. But even then aslo it does not store the ajax call result in the cache and everytime it makes ajax call for same thing.

```
$.ajax(
                            {
                                url: 'abc.aspx/getInfo',
                                cache: true,
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: '{userID: "' + id+ '"}', // id is a variabe
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                beforeSend: function() {
                                    // somthing...  
                                },
                               success: function(response, textStatus) {
                                 // something....
                               }
                             }
```

Can any one tell me why it is happening. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC cache works with GET requests. For POST requests you need to have your server side script send proper [HTTP cache headers](http://dotnetperls.com/cache-aspnet).

Comment: I was trying using type:'POST'. But it was showing some error. So can I replace 'POST' with 'GET'

Comment: but when I have replaced POST with GET the function in the codebehid which is used to fetch data from database  was not executed and in firebug it showed 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: @ANP, yes I see that you are using ASPX PageMethods. Unfortunately they only work with POST.